# ¿Qué significa "crack" en el contexto de futbol?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, modismos, significado

> Marta, la "crack" de Brasil, hace historia en el futbol.

Lo ví en el Publinews.

Pregunté a mi hija teenager y no podía darme una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Según el Diccionario de la lengua española, [***crack***](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BBln4J5) es:

> Voz ingl
>   1. m. cocaína en piedra.
>   **2. m. Deportista de extraordinaria calidad.**
>   3. m. Caballo que destaca en las carreras.

Aparte de esa acepción "oficial", se utiliza en sentido figurado para una persona que destaca entre los demás o ha alcanzado un logro destacado, en cualquier ámbito, no solo deportivo. Por ejemplo:

> Es un *crack* con los números.

Sobre la etimología, parece que esa acepción está tomada directamente del adjetivo inglés. El diccionario [**Merriam-Webster**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crack) lo define como:

> **of superior excellence or ability** // *a crack marksman*

Y [**Etymonline**](https://www.etymonline.com/classic/search?q=crack):

> Adjectival meaning "top-notch, superior, excellent, first rate" (as in a crack shot) is slang from 1793, perhaps from earlier verbal sense of "do any thing with quickness or smartness" [Johnson], or from the verb in the sense of "speak boastingly" and suggesting "having qualities to be proud of" [Century Dictionary]

Expresiones similares: "ser un campeón", "ser una máquina", "ser un hacha".

Comment: ¿Se usa en todo el mundo hispanoblante esta palabra? Nunca la he visto antes.

Comment: @Obie2.0 - antes de que empezara.  Porque *empezar* es un verbo tipo *-ar*.

Comment: Yo creo que solamente en español se usa así, es decir como sustantivo. En inglés la palabra se utiliza como adjetivo, por ejemplo en la oración presentada en esta respuesta, pero no para referirse a una persona sin adjetivo adicional. Nunca había oído esta forma (persona X es un crack) antes de que empezara a ver noticas en español.